When A results/stems/arises from B, are A and B always bad?
I looked for examples of results/stems/arises from and found only negative ones.
So, when A results/stems/arises from B, are A and B always bad?
I was thinking that the answer is yes, so I decided to search for some phrases used when A and B are positive or neutral and found this:

A is brought about by B. (An increase in sales was brought about by the new marketing strategy.)

Please feel free to recommend some other phrases like brought about by. Thank you in advance!

Haven't you answered your own question by using an example with a good outcome? Or is the question not what the title asks?

I think you've misunderstood the question, I meant to say that when we use result/stem/arise from, we often refer to bad outcomes (I posted some links in reply to the answer below). However, I'm asking for phrases to refer to positive outcomes, such as bring about because I was able to easily find those positive-outcome examples containing "bring about", unlike the other three phrases.

"A is brought about by B" can be negative too. I think you are looking at usage patterns that don't exist.

Plenty of positives here.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/sentences/stem%20from
There is no rule that says any of your examples has to be negative.

Oh it's because I looked them up in these links: result from, arise from, stem from. Somehow all of the examples here are negative, which led to my assumption.
